# How to round the corners of the FullCalendar jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

While trying to customize the appearance of the FullCalendar jQuery plugin, I encountered a problem that I can't manage to fix myself.
To be more precise, I have been trying to round the corners of the header, and sadly, it isn't as simple as applying a border radius.

This is how I managed to make it look: 
http://185.81.157.248/learnardo/index2.php

As you can see the square  persists behind the , and editing impact the entire calendar.

Does anyone have any idea on what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: can you please update your question with a sample of code you are working with?

Comment: Thanks to your help I managed to fix the issue. I am truly grateful and I hope to be in a position to help someone else in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `border-collapse: separate;` to the table and set the proper backgrounds (e.g.: `background-color: black;` to the `tr` and `background-color: white;` to the `td`). It should do what you want.

```
<div class="fc-view fc-agendaWeek-view fc-agenda-view">
  <table style="border-collapse: separate;">
    <thead class="fc-head">
      <tr style="background-color: black;">
        <td class="fc-widget-header" style="background-color: white;">
```

You need to adjust your previous border radius rule (if you don't want them so round).

Here's a messed up snippet based on your page contents:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

            // gère la hauteur de la sidebar
            function adaptSideBar(){
                var hauteurEcran = $(window).height();
                var hauteurDiv = hauteurEcran - 110;
                $(".sidebarHeight").height(hauteurDiv);
            }
            
           
            // if the user resizes the window
            $( window ).resize(function() {
                // resize the sidebar
                adaptSideBar();
                // resize the calendar
                var hauteurEcran = $(window).height();
                var hauteurCalendar = hauteurEcran - 75;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', hauteurCalendar);
                //replace la timeline du calendrier
                setTimeline();
            });

                adaptSideBar();

                var hauteurEcran = $(window).height();
                var hauteurCalendar = hauteurEcran - 75;

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header:{
                        left: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
                        center: 'prev,title,next',
                        right: ''
                    },
                    columnFormat: { month: 'ddd', week: 'dddd', day: 'dddd d/M' },
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    firstDay: 1,
                    height: hauteurCalendar,
                    allDaySlot: false,
                    slotDuration: '01:00:00',
                    viewRender: function(view) {             
                        if(typeof(timelineInterval) != 'undefined'){
                          window.clearInterval(timelineInterval);
                        }
                        timelineInterval = window.setInterval(setTimeline, 60000);
                        try {
                          setTimeline();
                          drawLines();
                          scrollMe();

                        } catch(err) {}
                    },
                    scrollTime: $("#timenow").val(),
                    editable : true,
                    events: [
                        {
                            title  : 'event2',
                            start  : '2015-06-26T12:30:00',
                            end    : '2015-06-26T15:30:00',
                            color  : "red"
                        },
                        {
                            title  : 'event3',
                            start  : '2015-06-27T12:22:00',
                            end    : '2015-06-27T18:34:00'
                        }
                    ]
                }); // fin du calendar

                //gestion de la scrollbar du calendar
                function scrollMe(){
                    
                    $(".fc-time-grid-container").niceScroll({
                        cursorcolor: "#919191",
                        scrollspeed: 200,
                        horizrailenabled: false,
                        hidecursordelay: 2000
                    });
                }

                // gestion des autres scrollbars
                $(".scrollme").niceScroll({
                    cursorcolor: "#919191",
                    scrollspeed: 200,
                    horizrailenabled: false,
                    hidecursordelay: 2000
                });

                function drawLines(){
                    $(".fc-agendaWeek-view .fc-body .fc-widget-content .fc-time-grid-container .fc-time-grid .fc-slats table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").append("&lt;div class='linecalendar25'&gt;&lt;/div&gt;");
                    $(".fc-agendaWeek-view .fc-body .fc-widget-content .fc-time-grid-container .fc-time-grid .fc-slats table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").append("&lt;div class='linecalendar50'&gt;&lt;/div&gt;");
                    $(".fc-agendaWeek-view .fc-body .fc-widget-content .fc-time-grid-container .fc-time-grid .fc-slats table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").append("&lt;div class='linecalendar75'&gt;&lt;/div&gt;");
                }

                function setTimeline(view) {
                var slotsDiv  = $('.fc-slats:visible');
                var parentDiv = $('.fc-slats:visible').parent();
                var timeline = parentDiv.children(".timeline");
                if (timeline.length == 0) { //if timeline isn't there, add it
                    timeline = $("&lt;hr&gt;").addClass("timeline");
                    parentDiv.prepend(timeline);
                }

              var curTime = new Date();

              var curCalView = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView');
              if (curCalView.intervalStart &lt; curTime &amp;&amp; curCalView.intervalEnd &gt; curTime) {
                timeline.show();
              } else {
                timeline.hide();
                return;
              }
              var calMinTimeInMinutes = strTimeToMinutes(curCalView.opt("minTime"));
              var calMaxTimeInMinutes = strTimeToMinutes(curCalView.opt("maxTime"));
              var curSeconds = (( ((curTime.getHours() * 60) + curTime.getMinutes()) - calMinTimeInMinutes) * 60) + curTime.getSeconds();
              var percentOfDay = curSeconds / ((calMaxTimeInMinutes - calMinTimeInMinutes) * 60);

              var topLoc = Math.floor(slotsDiv.height() * percentOfDay);
              var timeCol = $('.fc-time:visible');
              timeline.css({top: topLoc + "px", left: (timeCol.outerWidth(true))+"px"});

              if (curCalView.name == "agendaWeek") { //week view, don't want the timeline to go the whole way across
                var dayCol = $(".fc-today:visible");
                var left = dayCol.position().left + 1;
                var width = dayCol.width() + 1;
                timeline.css({left: left + "px", width: width + "px"});
              }
            }

            function strTimeToMinutes(str_time) {
              var arr_time = str_time.split(":");
              var hour = parseInt(arr_time[0]);
              var minutes = parseInt(arr_time[1]);
              return((hour * 60) + minutes);
            }

        });
```

```css
html {
    background-color: #000000;
}
body {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.no-gutter > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.titreSubNavBar {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#logo {
    left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
#customIcon1 {
    font-size: 2.1em;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}
#customIcon2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
#customIcon3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#customIcon4 {
    left: 77%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#customIcon5 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
#customIcon6 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 21%;
    top: 20%;
}
#customIcon7 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
#customIcon8 {
    margin-left: 4%;
}
#customIcon9 {
    position: relative;
    right: 4px;
}
#customIcon10 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 3px 7px 5px 5px !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
#customIcon11 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 3px 7px 5px 5px !important;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    top: 1px;
}
#customIcon12 {
    position: relative;
    right: 19px;
}
#newProjectButton {
    width: 110px;
}
.taskbloc {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    margin-left: 0;
}
.taskTitle {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.taskMinutes {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.heightTaskbar {
    height: 60px;
}
.containerRightSidebar {
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.blocInfoRightSidebar {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.pointsRightSidebar {
    bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 3em;
    position: relative;
}
.round {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #e53935 50%, #ff9800 100%);
    border: 3px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    width: 25px;
}
.bar {
    background: #e8e8e8 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: -19px;
    width: 4px;
}
.rowGoal {
    bottom: 8px;
    position: relative;
}
.containerGoalProgressbar {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.imageProfile {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 29px;
}
.profileName {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
#boutonAjoutProjet {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 17px 25px;
    position: fixed;
}
button {
    outline: medium none;
}
thead tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
thead tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300,700,400">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap3.3.4.css">
        <link href="dist/calendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="dist/calendar/myfullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Site Begins -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- first navbar -->
        
            <div class="row" id="navbar">
                <div class="myCol-md-2-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="myCol-md-2-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 profileBloc">
                    
                   
                </div>
            </div> 
            
            <!-- first navbar ends -->
            
            <!-- start subnavbar -->
            <div class="row">
                
                <!-- left side bar -->
                
                <div class="myCol-md-2-5">

                    
                </div>
                
                <!-- left side bar ends-->
                
                <!-- middle -->
                
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-ltr fc-unthemed"><div class="fc-toolbar"><div class="fc-left"><div class="fc-button-group"><button class="fc-agendaDay-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left" type="button">day</button><button class="fc-agendaWeek-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-state-active" type="button">week</button><button class="fc-month-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right" type="button">month</button></div></div><div class="fc-right"></div><div class="fc-center"><div><button class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-state-default" type="button"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow"></span></button><h2>Aug 31 &mdash; Sep 6, 2015</h2><button class="fc-next-button fc-button fc-state-default" type="button"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-right-single-arrow"></span></button></div></div><div class="fc-clear"></div></div><div class="fc-view-container" style=""><div class="fc-view fc-agendaWeek-view fc-agenda-view" style=""><table style="border-collapse: separate;"><thead class="fc-head" style=""><tr style="background-color: black;"><td class="fc-widget-header" style="background-color: white;"><div class="fc-row fc-widget-header"><table style=""><thead style=""><tr style=""><th class="fc-axis fc-widget-header" style="width: 37px; border-radius: 4px;"></th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-mon">Monday</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-tue">Tuesday</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-wed">Wednesday</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-thu">Thursday</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-fri">Friday</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat">Saturday</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun">Sunday</th></tr></thead></table></div></td></tr></thead><tbody class="fc-body"><tr><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-time-grid-container fc-scroller" style="height: 373px;" tabindex="5000"><div class="fc-time-grid"><hr class="timeline" style="top: 860px; left: 335px; width: 96px;"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"></td><td data-date="2015-08-31" class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past"></td><td data-date="2015-09-01" class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-past"></td><td data-date="2015-09-02" class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-past"></td><td data-date="2015-09-03" class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-today fc-state-highlight"></td><td data-date="2015-09-04" class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future"></td><td data-date="2015-09-05" class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future"></td><td data-date="2015-09-06" class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-slats"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>12am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>1am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>2am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>3am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>4am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>5am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>6am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>7am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>8am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>9am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>10am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>11am</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>12pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>1pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>2pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>3pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>4pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>5pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>6pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>7pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>8pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>9pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>10pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>11pm</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="linecalendar25"></div><div class="linecalendar50"></div><div class="linecalendar75"></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><hr class="fc-divider fc-widget-header" style="display: none;"><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><tbody><tr><td style="width: 37px;" class="fc-axis"></td><td><div class="fc-event-container"></div></td><td><div class="fc-event-container"></div></td><td><div class="fc-event-container"></div></td><td><div class="fc-event-container"></div></td><td><div class="fc-event-container"></div></td><td><div class="fc-event-container"></div></td><td><div class="fc-event-container"></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="09:48:10" id="timenow">                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <!-- middle ends -->
                
                
                <!-- right side bar -->
                
                <div class="myCol-md-2-5">
              

                </div>
                <!-- right side bar end -->
                
                
            </div>
            <!-- subnavbar ends -->
        </div>
        <!-- Site ends -->

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="dist/calendar/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/calendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

    


<div id="ascrail2000" class="nicescroll-rails" style="width: 5px; z-index: 1; cursor: default; position: absolute; top: 138.1px; left: 1079px; height: 373px; opacity: 0;"><div style="position: relative; top: 152px; float: right; width: 5px; height: 74px; background-color: rgb(145, 145, 145); border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); background-clip: padding-box; border-radius: 5px;"></div></div></body></html>
```

The important part is that you can see the table headers with rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

I used round corners on another answer (round cornered tables wasn't the actual problem, I just like tables with rounded corners). Just for kicks, not related to the question, but you can reorder the table by clicking the "Item" or "Price" header.

The CSS is the only thing you need, and it'll work as long as you are using proper table structure.

I almost forgot to mention, there is a way to create tables with rounded corners and collapsed borders (notice how thin your cell borders are compared to my table.), but it's a lot more involved, I could try to handle that in a new question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = document.getElementById('xtable'),
    tableHead = table.querySelector('thead'),
    tableHeaders = tableHead.querySelectorAll('th'),
    tableBody = table.querySelector('tbody');

  tableHead.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var tableHeader = e.target,
      textContent = tableHeader.textContent,
      tableHeaderIndex, isAscending, order;

    if (textContent !== 'add row') {
      while (tableHeader.nodeName !== 'TH') {
        tableHeader = tableHeader.parentNode;
      }
      tableHeaderIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tableHeaders, tableHeader);
      isAscending = tableHeader.getAttribute('data-order') === 'asc';
      order = isAscending ? 'desc' : 'asc';
      tableHeader.setAttribute('data-order', order);
      tinysort(tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr'), {
        selector: 'td:nth-child(' + (tableHeaderIndex + 1) + ')',
        order: order
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table.blue {
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 9px 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.blue th {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #2C7EDB;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.blue tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}
.blue tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #D3E9FF;
  color: #333;
}
.blue td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #264D73;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.blue thead th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}
.blue thead th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.blue tbody tr:last-child th:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.blue tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.blue tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinysort/2.2.2/tinysort.js"></script>
<table class="blue" id="xtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-order="asc">
        <a>Item
          </a>
            </th>
            <th>Qty
              </th>
                <th data-order="asc"><a>Price</a> </th>
            <th>Desc</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr> <td> Porche </td><td>1</td> <td> $100, 000.00 </td><td>Sports car</td> </tr>
      <tr><td>Toilet Paper</td> <td> 5 </td><td>$50.00</td> <td> 8 rolls </td></tr>
    <tr> <td> Laptop </td><td>1</td> <td> $600.00 </td><td>HP i7 12GB 1TB</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: The issue is now fixed, thank you very much for showing us this way to approach the problem.